# Unable to inline fonts from npm modules

Tags: html, css, angular, webpack, fonts

I am running Angular 8 with the Custom Webpack builder.

```
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
```

I have a reference to the `ngx-datatable`, and I reference the `css` as follows:

```
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css';
```

That referenced css file has a font-face like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "data-table";
  src:url("fonts/data-table.eot");
  src:url("fonts/data-table.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/data-table.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/data-table.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/data-table.svg#data-table") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

What I want to do is inline the data-table font file into my webpack'd build. My understanding is that, after installing the base64-inline-loader, I should be able to have a custom webpack config that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
 {
   test: /\.(jpe?g|png|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
   use: 'base64-inline-loader'
 }
    ]
  }
};
```

However, after running the build, nothing gets inlined, and I can see the browser is making a request to

```
http://localhost:4200/data-table.woff
```

It's not clear to me how to fix this. My understanding is that for files like .png, .woff, .eot, etc, the default Angular webpack configuration will use the file-loader, which will spit out a hashed version of the file in the dist directory. However even after adding the base64-inline-loader, I am still seeing the files get copied and hashed, instead of inlined.

**Edit**

I believe my problem is related to [Angular 7, svg and sass how to set relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590073/angular-7-svg-and-sass-how-to-set-relative-path), but I'm still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657087/webpack-inline-font-with-url-loader

Comment: Could you please share you complete `webpack.config` plus the full command line with which you are calling it? What is the output of `npm ls webpack`?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your `Webpack.config.js` might need some tweaking?

I prefer to keep the command line clean (here: `webpack --config Webpack.config.js`) and put everything into the configuration file. Assuming that you are using a newer version of Webpack, I suggest a configuration file similar to this this

```
var path = require('path'); // this is essential for path.resolve()

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './yourEntryPage.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // specifies the output
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
 devtool: "source-map", // for debugging webpack's output.
  module: {
    rules: [
        {   test: /\.jsx$|\.es6$|\.js$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['react'],
                }
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {   test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: {  
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: { 
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'images/'
                }
            }
        },
        {   test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff(2)?)$/, // modified regex matching files with font extension
            use: 'base64-inline-loader'
        }           
    ]
  }
};
```

You cannot directly use this configuration file, but I hope my suggestion gives you an idea on what a not-so-minimal configuration for Webpack could look like. The `Webpack.config.js` you suggested might not only have a path problem, but might also miss to specify the hierarchy of the different loaders. It could well be that your inline-loader case-statement is never reached.

**Note**: I do not know `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser`, but I hope it helps anyhow if that package does not interfere too much with `Webpack.config.js`. My experience tells me that in 95% of the cases the cuplrit is a webpack configuration issue. A `--verbose`, `--progress` or `-d` might become handy, see [Webpack's CLI documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been getting closer to a workable solution. The problem seems Angular specific. As mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590073/angular-7-svg-and-sass-how-to-set-relative-path, the postcssPluginCreator seems to override any other settings.

Answer (score 0):

The webpack will inline the font into your output .js file (or .woff file) but will not *serve* it. This means that you have to manually add this font in your static assets in angular.json:

```
"assets": [
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/swimlane_or_whatever/assets/",
                "output": "my-assets"
              },
```

The code above means that after you run the development server, the resource `/my-assets/fonts.woff` will be resolved and passed to the client.